# Is this possible to know when my login session has been expired in laravel and redirect automatically

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.4

This is my laravel `session.php` configuration.

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
```

It working and redirect me after sometime, I don't know the time when it redirect. I expected to redirect my application to login page after 120 minute.

How can i redirect my application automatically after session expire ?

Comment: just check whether session is set or not, if it is expired than it means 2 hours has been passed https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-to-custom-url-after-session-timeout.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя, But why my application didn't redirect after 2 hours. it redirect after some time and i want to know when session going to expire.

Comment: @Md.SukelAli maybe you're authenticated with the "remember me" cookie, if not the session should be expired after 2 hours as expected